# How to convert string to hex in Python?

Tags: python, hex

I using the pyqt5 line edit box as my input boxes. I want to take the input from the input boxes and convert it from string to hex to send to serial capture. For example I did this but I didn't succeed:

```
a = hex(self.slave1.text())
b = hex(self.function1.text())
c = hex(self.address_msb1.text())
d = hex(self.address_lsb1.text())
e = hex(self.register_msb1.text())
f = hex(self.register_lsb1.text())
g = hex(self.crc_lsb1.text())
h = hex(self.crc_msb1.text())
hexConvert = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

Imagine:

```
a = "01"
b = "03"
c = "00"
d = "0A"
e = "00"
f = "04"
g = "64"
h = "0B"
```

And my expected output is

```
[0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x04, 0x64, 0x0B]
```

Comment: No, the question is string to int. As explained before, python will always "show" you integers, even if you create a list of hex based numbers: `print([0x32, 0x2f])` will output `[50, 47]`. It doesn't matter the base you *think*, the number won't change.

Comment: To clarify: `0b101101 == 0x2d == 0o55 == 45` (binary, hex, octal, int) results in `True`. And python always uses *integers* for `__repr__`esentation.

Comment: Voted to reopen this question. A "duplicate" question asks for string already in hex format to be converted into integer. This is not what this question is about at all.

There may be much more elegant answers to this question (I have few good approaches in mind), but I cannot post answer, becasue someone smart thinks this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 16):

The hex() function converts a specified *integer number* into a hexadecimal *string representation*.

Use `int(x, base)` with 16 as base to convert the string x to an integer. Call hex(number) with the integer as number to convert it to hexadecimal.

```
hex_string = "0xAA"

"0x" also required

an_integer = int(hex_string, 16)

hex_value = hex(an_integer)

print(hex_value)
```

Output

> 0xaa

Comment: but i taking output from the qline edit box. If i enter in put "AA" so how to make it 0xaa?

Comment: @Tenish as explained in the linked *duplicate* question, use `int(string_value, 16)`. Please, don't rush your answers, read, *study*, and **understand**.

Comment: a = self.slave1.text (), self.slave1.text () will have the value "AA" (the data you entered), you just need to add 0x. a = "0x" + self.slave1.text ().

Comment: @ThuấnĐàoMinh no, there's no need for that, `int()` is well capable of understanding the input even without the `0x` prefix.

Comment: @musiccamante, Thank you so much. I have just learned new knowledge.

Comment: @ThuấnĐàoMinh also, your first sentence is wrong: `hex()` converts a *number* to string (no matter its type or base), not a string to hex: there's no point in "converting to hex" from a programming point of view; an integer is just an integer, the base is just a "human" representation: 15 is just 15 in decimal, 0xf as hex, or `1111` in binary, 3 hands with open fingers, but it's still *"integer of value 15"*.

Comment: @musiccamante, i have eddied my answer. Thank you so much for reviewing.